# C# DB2 EF Insert erorr

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db2

I currently have some problems inserting a new row into a table. The problem is likely, that the statement has double-quotes surrounding the primary key for whatever reason.

```
select "OID" as ""OID"" 
from new table (insert into "PAQ"."TPAQ100_AUFTRAG"("EKVNR", "AUFTRAG_ERSTELLT_AM", "NACHNAME", "VORNAME", "GEBURTSDATUM", "SACHBEARBEITER_NACHNAME", "SACHBEARBEITER_VORNAME", "SACHBEARBEITER_USER", "DIENSTSTELLE", "LEI_ARZT_ANGEFORDERT", "LEI_ZAHNARZT_ANGEFORDERT", "LEI_APO_ANGEFORDERT", "LEI_KH_ANGEFORDERT", "LEI_SONSTIGE_LE_ANGEFORDERT", "GUELTIG_VON", "GUELTIG_BIS", "AUSGABEWEG", "AUFTRAG_HERKUNFT")
    values (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17))
```

Now I already have `EnableEFCaseSensitivity` on false and honestly have no clue where the quotes come from. I do use the `Column` attribute, but not for `OID`. I only set the `Key` attribute and that's it. The Columns (as well as the name of the table) are all in Caps.

The error is:

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token """" was found following "select "OID" as ".  Expected tokens may include:  "".

The model-class:

```
    [Table("PAQ.TPAQ100_AUFTRAG")]
    public class Auftrag
    {
        [Key]
        public long OID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Column("EKVNR")]
        public string Ekvnr { get; set; }

        [Column("AUFTRAG_ERSTELLT_AM")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60)]
        [Column("NACHNAME")]
        public string Nachname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Column("VORNAME")]
        public string Vorname { get; set; }

        [Column("GEBURTSDATUM", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime GebDat { get; set; }

        [StringLength(32)]
        [Column("SACHBEARBEITER_NACHNAME")]
        public string SachbearbeiterNachname { get; set; }

        [StringLength(32)]
        [Column("SACHBEARBEITER_VORNAME")]
        public string SachbearbeiterVorname { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        [Column("SACHBEARBEITER_USER")]
        public string SachbearbeiterUser { get; set; }

        [StringLength(7)]
        [Column("DIENSTSTELLE")]
        public string SachbearbeiterDst { get; set; }

        [Column("LEI_ARZT_ANGEFORDERT")]
        public short AerztlicheLeistungen { get; set; }

        [Column("LEI_ZAHNARZT_ANGEFORDERT")]
        public short ZahnaerztlicheLeistungen { get; set; }

        [Column("LEI_APO_ANGEFORDERT")]
        public short Arzneimittel { get; set; }

        [Column("LEI_KH_ANGEFORDERT")]
        public short KrankenhausBehandlung { get; set; }


        [Column("LEI_SONSTIGE_LE_ANGEFORDERT")]
        public short SonstigeLeistungen { get; set; }

        [Column("GUELTIG_VON", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime GueltigAb { get; set; }

        [Column("GUELTIG_BIS", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime GueltigBis { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(1)]
        [Column("AUSGABEWEG", TypeName = "character")]
        public string AusgabeWeg { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(1)]
        [Column("AUFTRAG_HERKUNFT", TypeName = "character")]
        public string AuftragHerkunft { get; set; }
    }
```

The repository-function:

```
public void Create(Auftrag auftrag)
{
    Logger.LogInfo($"Versuche den Auftrag für Versicherten {auftrag.Nachname}, {auftrag.Vorname} in die Auftragsdatenbank zu schreiben");
    auftrag.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    _context.Auftraege.Add(auftrag);
    //Loggt die Query zwecks Fehleranalyse
    _context.Database.Log = Logger.LogInfo;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The context-class:

```
public partial class AuftragDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AuftragDbContext(DbConnection db2Connection)
            : base(db2Connection, true)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Auftrag> Auftraege { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.Ekvnr)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.Nachname)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.Vorname)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.SachbearbeiterNachname)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.SachbearbeiterVorname)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.SachbearbeiterUser)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.SachbearbeiterDst)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.AuftragHerkunft)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Auftrag>()
                .Property(e => e.AusgabeWeg)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dient dem Abfangen von Exceptions im Prozess des Sicherns der datenbankseitigen Operationen
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                return base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbValEx)
            {
                var values = dbValEx.EntityValidationErrors;
                if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
                throw;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException dbUpEx)
            {
                throw dbUpEx;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gibt die Datenbankconnection abhängig von der aktuellen Domäne zurück
    /// </summary>
    public static class AuftragContextFactory
    {
        private static string _connectionString = null;

        private static DB2Connection GetConnectionString()
        {
            if (_connectionString != null)
            {
                return new DB2Connection(_connectionString);
            }

            var connstrBulder = new DakampClientConnectionStringBuilder(EnvironmentHandler.Environment);
            var connStr = connstrBulder.GetClientConnectionString(DatabaseType.AuftragsDB);
            var db2ConStrBldr = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder(connStr)
            {
                //Queries laufen so lange, bis sie durch sind unabhängig vom CommandTimeout
                QueryTimeout = 0,
                EnableEFCaseSensitivity = false,
                ConcurrentAccessResolution = "CurrentlyCommitted",
            };
            _connectionString = db2ConStrBldr.ConnectionString;
            return new DB2Connection(_connectionString);
        }

        public static AuftragDbContext AuftragDb => new AuftragDbContext(GetConnectionString());
    }
```

I've spent the last few hours searching for a solution without finding anything helpful at all.

Comment: I assume this is a statement generated by Entity Framework? If so, which version?

Comment: Also, that begs the question: what if you do use the `Column` attribute?

Comment: It's EF 6.1.3 and I tried using the Column-Attribute for the key (OID), too, but nothing changed.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a weird bug in the DB2 data provider. You could raise an issue at their product site. In the mean time, you could work around it by removing double quotes from the query string in a [command interceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Ugh - well I think I'll just use ExecuteSqlCommand then, because I can't seem to find a proper example of modifying the query with the command interceptor.

Comment: You can inherit from `DbCommandInterceptor` and override the appropriate methods to modify the command's text.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not a 100% satisfying answer you can use Command Interceptors to modify the sql-query, before it is exexuted:

```
public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
{
    command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("\"\"", "\"").Trim();
    Logger.LogInfo("ReaderExecuted: " +
                   $" IsAsync: {interceptionContext.IsAsync}, Command Text: {command.CommandText}");
}
```

All I did was to replace double-quotes with one quote and it's working properly.